# Nvidia drivers and dist-upgrade on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu, gpu-driver

I have Ubuntu `20.10` and a [ASUS Phoenix GeForce® GTX 1660 OC edition](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Graphics-Cards/All-series/PH-GTX1660-O6G/) video card.

I have been using [these PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) drivers since last year and never had any issue. Today I was updating my system and after running `apt upgrade` I've noticed:

```
dpkg: warning: downgrading libnvidia-common-460 from 465.24.02-1pop0~1620080500~20.10~350b91c to 460.67-1pop0~1616430777~20.10~71e1ad1
```

Then I tried to run `apt dist-upgrade` (which is something I usually don't use) and found:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libatomic1:i386 libbsd0:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi8ubuntu1:i386
  libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386 libllvm11:i386 libnvidia-cfg1-460 libnvidia-common-460 libnvidia-compute-460:i386
  libnvidia-decode-460:i386 libnvidia-decode-460 libnvidia-encode-460:i386 libnvidia-encode-460 libnvidia-extra-460 libnvidia-fbc1-460:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-460 libnvidia-gl-460
  libnvidia-gl-460:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-460:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-460 libpciaccess0:i386 libsensors5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libvulkan1:i386 libwayland-client0:i386 libx11-6:i386
  libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-randr0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386
  libxcb1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxnvctrl0 libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-460 nvidia-dkms-460
  nvidia-kernel-common-460 nvidia-kernel-common-465 nvidia-kernel-source-460 nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-460 screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  nvidia-driver-440 nvidia-driver-460
The following packages have been kept back:
  libnvidia-compute-460 libnvidia-decode-460 libnvidia-encode-460 libnvidia-fbc1-460 libnvidia-gl-460 libnvidia-ifr1-460
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libnvidia-cfg1-460 libnvidia-extra-460 nvidia-compute-utils-460 nvidia-kernel-source-460 nvidia-utils-460 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460
6 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 26.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,523 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Is there any issue here?

It seems to me that if I proceed with `apt dist-upgrade` the latest drivers from the PPA will be removed, right?
Is there anything I have to do in specific to avoid `apt dist-upgrade` command to suggest those updates?

Thanks

Comment: you have a mess somehow between nvidia driver 440 and 460 and different archs. What is the active driver? Check with `nvidia-smi`

Comment: @pLumo the default seems to be `460` (https://ibb.co/rH28NNM)